# fprintf use in C

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I am using fprintf to store the values entered by user  in a file . Code is not working as expected (First thing that after prompting "Do you want to continue? Y or N  : " program is automatically taking some value and continues the loop . Secondly it is not storing the value input by user into intended file . Update: I am able to let program prompt use whether to continue loop or not by putting space in scanf before %c but still file admin_db.txt is not getting populated properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {

char str[30];
int a[10];

}UNIX;

int main()

{

UNIX admin;
char ch;
FILE *fp;

fp=fopen("admin_db.txt","w+");

while(1)

{
printf("\nEnter the name of admin :  ");
 scanf("%s",&admin.str);

 printf("\nEnter the age of admin : ");
  scanf("%d",&admin.a);

  fprintf(fp,"%s%t%d",admin.str,admin.a);

  printf("\nDo you want to continue ? Y or N :");
   scanf("%c",&ch);

   if(ch=='n' || ch=='N')
     break;

}

fclose(fp);

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the name of admin :  Akhil

Enter the age of admin : 23

Do you want to continue ? Y or N :        //Automatically taking some value                                        //                                        other than n or N and continuing loop.
Enter the name of admin :  sukhi

Enter the age of admin : 30

Do you want to continue ? Y or N :
Enter the name of admin :
Enter the age of admin : ^C
```

Also , sizeof file admin_db.txt is of 0 bytes.

Comment: `%t` is not a valid [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specifier (that I know of), did you mean `\t`?

Comment: Many times a duplicate.  The `scanf()` leaves the newline in the input buffer; the `scanf("%c", …)` grabs the newline.  Put a space in front of the `%c`:  scanf(" %c", &ch);` to skip the white space.  Check the return value from `scanf()`, every time.  If it isn't the number of values you expected (1 in your code), there's a problem.

Comment: @Kninnug  you are right  I meant \t , anyway situation stands same.

Comment: Wrong (or not best) duplicate chosen.  Suggest [SO 217074](http://stackoverflow.com/q/217074) instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I put space before %c in scanf now and it is now prompting user to enter a value and waits for input but even if I enter y (yes want to continue) program is exiting .

Comment: Did you print out the value read into `ch`?  The first and simplest step in debugging is to check that the program sees what you think it sees.

Comment: in `scanf`, `&admin.str` should be just `admin.str` since `%s` expects a `char *` similarly in `fprintf`, '%d' expects an `int` which `admin.a` is not..... there are more type errors, compile with warnings enabled.

Comment: yes , checked .  
Enter the name of admin :  akhil

Enter the age of admin : 23

Do you want to continue ? Y or N :y
value you entered in ch is y

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush `stdin` before taking additional input.  The following is a portable method:

```
int ch;
while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
```

Comment: For this `ch` must be an `int` (OP has `ch` declared as `char`).

Comment: @Kninnug: Thanks. Updated my answer. :)

Comment: not working , still exiting even if I enter Y or y. Also before entering into loop compiler is waiting for user to enter value in order to execute loop , if you press enter it exits (because of your code logic '\n' )

Comment: Below is the Answer : #include<stdio.h>
typedef struct {

 char str[40];
 int a[5] ;

}UNIX;
int main()

{

FILE *fp;
char ch='y';
  UNIX admin;

fp=fopen("/home/akhils/file_dir/admin_db.data","a");
int i=0;
while(1)
{

  printf("Enter the name of admin : ");
  scanf("%s[^\n]",admin.str);
 printf("\nEnter age of admin : ");
  scanf("%d[^\n]",admin.a);
 printf("\nDo you want to continue ? Y or N : " ) ;
  scanf(" %c",&ch);
 fprintf(fp,"%s \t %d\n",admin.str,admin.a[0]);
  i++;
  if(ch=='N' || ch=='n')
  break;

 }
fclose(fp);
}