# trying to scan strings to 2 different elements of a struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, scanf

I tried to scan 2 different strings to 2 different elements of the same struct and I don't know why its not working.

This is my code:

```
struct qRegStudents{
  char studID[6];
  char studName[25];
};

typedef struct qRegStudents students;

int RegStudent() {
  students Student;
  char temp[6];

  printf("Enter ID Number: ");
  scanf(" %6s",Student.studID);
  printf("Enter Name: ");
  scanf(" %25s",Student.studName);

  printf("%s",Student.studID);

  return 0;
}
```

I input the student ID as "123456" and then the name as "josh". It prints "123456josh" as just the student ID

Comment: `char temp[6];` _looks_ unused (and hopefully OP is not truly using it somehow).  Suggest removing it as its just noise and may contribute to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049153/trying-to-scan-strings-to-2-different-elements-of-a-struct-in-c#comment87114717_50049240).

Comment: You might also want to check out this question about multiple scanfs leaving carriage return characters in the buffer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Comment: Also see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217074/parsing-input-with-scanf-in-c

Comment: How are you expecting `printf` to know to print six characters in this line of code: `printf("%s",Student.studID);`?

Comment: Take the tour, read How to Ask, and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. You do need to leave room in studId for the terminal null character. Test your program with "12345" as the student Id, you'll see that you get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't allocate enough space in the `studID` field to hold 6 characters plus the null terminator.  Change the definition to:

```
struct qRegStudents{
    char studID[7];
    char studName[25];
};
```

Edit... Best to include a `\n` at the end of the `printf` string to make sure it gets flushed to stdout.

Comment: still prints "123456josh" for Student.studID

Comment: I don't believe you.  Are you sure you recompiled?

Comment: @JoshRobertson Please use `printf("_%s_\n",Student.studID);` and show the output to prove your statement.

Answer (score 2):

your program have a undefined behavior as there is no memory space you kept for `'\0'` at the end of `studID` and `studName`. Allocate enough memory location.

make it like

```
struct qRegStudents{
        char studID[7]; /* plus 1 for terminating \0 char at end */
        char studName[26];
};
```

Also do `fflush(stdout)` to clear `stdout` stream or use `\n`. for e.g

```
printf("%s\n",Student.studID);
printf("%s\n",Student.studName);
```

Always compile your code with warning enable flags. For e.g `-Wall` flag. It will tell you something about unused variable(`temp[6]`), read it.

Comment: `-Wall` does not include all recommended warnigs. Beginner should enable all of them.